# C++ messagebox with TCHAR and string concatenation

Tags: c++, messagebox

Can somebody please tell me how I can output szFileName in a messagebox?

My attempt below does not work

```
//Retrieve the path to the data.dat in the same dir as our app.dll is located

TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH+1];
GetModuleFileName(_Module.m_hInst, szFileName, MAX_PATH+1);
StrCpy(PathFindFileName(szFileName), _T("data.dat"));

FILE *file =fopen(szFileName,"rb");
if (file)
{
    fseek( file,iFirstByteToReadPos, SEEK_SET);
    fread(bytes,sizeof(unsigned char), iLenCompressedBytes, file);
    fclose(file);
}
else
{
    MessageBox(NULL, szFileName + " not found", NULL, MB_OK);
    DebugBreak();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannt add:

```
szFileName + " not found",
```

Simple fix:

```
MessageBox(NULL, szFileName, L"File not found", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support '+' to concatenate char or TCHAR arrays. You need to use a string class for that, or do it the C-style  way with strcat and a buffer on the stack.

Since you're using C++, you can use CString if you are using ATL/mfc, or you can use something like:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

...
MessageBox(NULL, tstring(szFileName) + " not found", NULL, MB_OK);
```

The usual C++ plumbing has been left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: MessageBox(NULL, (tstring(szFileName) + " not found").c_str(), NULL, MB_OK); ?